Force Tab Event on WebView2
i am trying to automatize a process in one of our sites, i am using c# into an .net project with the WebView2 component. I was checking for a method or way to force the webview to do a tab. It's like when I do a focus or a click by code in javascript, it doesn't work. So i was trying to simulate the tab keyboard event.
I tried things like:
await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.querySelectorAll('.myclass input')[0].focus()");
await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress'," + "{   key: 'Tab'}))");

Can you help me?

You need to add event listener for that tab button to the appropriate component.
This is more of a Javascript question. You may look into AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync method for wiring it up.

Does this answer your question? Create tabs using WebView2 - Edge

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73087225/10024425
